# Why does buildout delete my instance/etc and Extensions folder each time it is run?

Tags: plone, buildout

Everytime I run buildout to add a product egg, it deletes all the stuff under parts.

How do people deal with this?

Comment: That is a feature not a bug; you deal with it by not editing anything in parts.

Comment: It is a sucky "feature". Why cant plone.recipe.zope2instance not update zope.conf if it has been modified? Or keep the Extensions folder if present? Adding an egg to the buildout should not mean you lose all your saved external methods.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update:** To only register a new egg to the instance, you can use buildout's install-command to only build specific parts like this:

```
buildout install instance
```

---

"Why does buildout delete my instance/etc and Extensions folder each time it is run?"

-> Because that's what buildout is made for: To build automatically the parts, the way it is defined in the buildout-configuration-file.
Not deleting former dirs and files would easily result in conflicts and errors, I guess. Can anyone confirm?

"How do people deal with this?"

-> By not putting anything in the parts directory at all ;) No seriously, it is not recommended to do it.

What's your specific use-case?

Comment: All my External methods are gone. My customized zope.conf is gone. Just because I want to add an egg to test it out.

Comment: You should regard zope.conf as autogenerated. Never edit it directly. Customize Zope setup via buildout configuration directives. And, there's probably been no reason to use external methods since Plone 3 made it easy to use Python packages.

Comment: Look at it this way... I just want to add an egg. This should just add the relevant path to the interpreter script. Why does this involve recreating the zope.conf files? We are not deleting the Data.fs, are we? In the same manner the zope.conf file should also not be considered a scratch artifact. Just my 2 cents!

Comment: Get your point. Maybe would be cool to write a script, that'll only actualises the eggs-registration. Does anyone know, if that could be possible?

Comment: This answer suggests to not include the parts you only want to be built once in the parts-section, and instead build them once with buildout's "install"-option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063730/buildout-with-part-build-with-cython/40761561

Answer (score 4):

you can put your customization of zope.conf directly in the buildout. Also, in Plone 4 Extensions is not created anymore, you can put it somewhere else.

For example, this: http://plone.org/products/products.migrateexternalmethods will move your existing external methods to an egg, so you can put them in svn and manage them as you do for your code.

Comment: @sureshvv: Did you give this a try? Would be the most sane way, imho: eggs, eggs, eggs ;) Even if you don't use the mentioned product and transfer it yourself, Yuris answer is worth an acceptance, I think. +1 from me

Answer (score 4):

As has been pointed out already, you should not put any customizations in the "parts" directory directly.  You need to put it elsewhere.

Extension methods are generally not needed these days but if you wish to use them, you have a couple of options:

**Option 1**
Create an Extensions folder in your own product.  Put your module at "my.product/my/product/Extensions/mymodule.py" and reference it in the ZMI as "my.product.mymodule"

**Option 2**
Use the "zope-conf-additional" parameter in plone.recipe.zope2instance to add another location for the Extensions folder like so:

```
[instance]
recipe = plone.recipe.zope2instance
...
zope-conf-additional = extensions ${buildout:directory}/Extensions
```